# Installing Slax on my hard drive

Tags: linux, installation

I am running Slax Linux from my USB drive and now I want to install it in my computer. What should I do?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is included, there is a Slax Installer included. This sort of thing is easily found either in official documentation, forums or IRC. [Source](http://www.slax.org/forum.php?action=view&parentID=4456)